# Compile IPA file, for ios with adobe flash

Tags: iphone, ios, actionscript-3, flash, air

I am flash developer and I want to create an application for iphone (ios). For that reason I have registered on developer.apple.com, bought developer license, created mobileprovision and .p12 files.Also, in adobe flash I created usual layer and compiled as followed: as a target, I chose ios air 3,6. Also, I linked it with mobileprovision and .p12 files and I made compilation ipa file for ios. Also, with USB cable I connected my iphone (operating system 7.0.2) to computer and with the help of itunes I installed ipa file created by me. 
After that I tried to run my app on iphone, but below aplication icon instead of application name it is written "installing ...", but after I am restarting iphone, it is written "waiting". I know that there are other alternative programming languages for creating ios applications, but I am flash developer and I want to create iphone applications with adobe flash.
Other apk files created with adobe flash work on android operating system without any problem.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvqUe.jpg

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear as to what is actually happening? Are you launching from within Flash or using iTunes to install the ipa? The fact it says installing doesn't really point to a Flash problem as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me when my certificate or provisioning profile wasn't correctly setup.

Is your device registered to the apple developer program and the provisioning profile? Are you using the correct certificate/provisioning profile combination? But if I had to take a stab in the dark I would say that you are building for AdHoc or AppStore distribution but using a development certificate...

Also, install the latest version of AIR (3.9). Previous versions aren't compiled against iOS 7.

Comment: I compiled to iOS7 with Air 3.7 with no problems, afaik 3.9 is still in beta

Comment: Also if you're running on a mac try installing the app via xcode's organiser. It normally gives you better error info than itunes.

Comment: Thanks for the link! I usually install via Flash. For errors and alerts I use the console of iPhone Configuration Utility.